# How to force 768×1024 screen view to 360×640 view in iPad

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a problem with mobile responsive view, if the apps is running in an tablet or iPad, the screen will be fit the screen of iPad, and I want to force this screen view (iPad) to smaller screen view (360×640). Anyone have any idea how to do it?

This screen view:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this yes.

The theory is that you set the `--ion-grid-width` variable to the max value width that you want the app to display in, and then wrap your entire page contents in an `ion-grid`.

As you can see from my snippet below, my solution was inspired by an article on the [official Ionic blog](https://blog.ionicframework.com/tips-tricks-for-ionic-on-desktop/) but I think it was targeting Ionic 3 so I had to make some tweaks.

I'm trying to remember from an app that I implemented this in at the start of the year. Here are the relevant snippets:

I put this one in variables.scss but any top-level sass file will do:

```
/** RTP - Custom Grid Breakpoints For Desktop **/
// Inspired By https://blog.ionicframework.com/tips-tricks-for-ionic-on-desktop/
$custom-grid-max-width: 768px;

ion-grid {
    --ion-grid-width: #{$custom-grid-max-width};
}

ion-header ion-toolbar[fixed],
ion-footer ion-toolbar[fixed] {
  --padding-end: calc((100% - #{$custom-grid-max-width}) / 2);
  --padding-start: calc((100% - #{$custom-grid-max-width}) / 2);
}
/** END RTP - Custom Grid Breakpoints For Desktop **/
```

I've clamped my max-width to `768px;`, you can change it to your preferred value.

Then for the pages, you do something like this:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar fixed>
    <ion-title text-center class="logo-holder">
      Example
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-grid fixed>
    Normal Ionic content in here.
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar fixed>
    <ion-buttons slot="primary">
      <ion-button color="primary" fill="solid" size="large" href="/add">
        <ion-icon slot="start" name="play"></ion-icon>
        Add
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

So you can see the toolbars have the `fixed` attribute. I have also put this `fixed` on the `ion-grid` wrapper as well. You will have to experiment if that's required of if I was just a confused n00b (this was my first app).

This clamps it a max of a tablet-ish size:

[image]

You can see from my red lines that the background and the toolbar container still extend full width but the content is clamped to a max width of 768px;